# "esse" vs "este", portuguese, and "this" vs "that" in English

Tags: grammar, pronouns

In Portuguese I have the pronouns **"esse"** and **"este"**, the first to abstract and not touchable themes, the following for objects or people, how should I use in the corresponding English words?

For example:

**esse** <-> **this**

> "Esse assunto não é adequado a este forum" <-> "this subject is not consistent with this forum"

**este** <-> **this/that**

> " Este movel deveria estar naquela sala" <-> This mobile should be in that room

Comment: Outside of this being a translation question (off-topic), is there some reason why English would not use "this/that" for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This* and *that* don't have anything to do with abstract versus concrete items.  It has to do with, from the point of the speaker/writer, what the "current object" of a conversation or sentence is.

Google provides a good definition of *this*:

> 1. used to identify a specific person or thing close at hand or being indicated or experienced.
> 2. referring to a specific thing or situation just mentioned.

*That* is used similarly, but used to refer to something *not* close at hand, or a specific thing or situation *previously* mentioned.  (*That* can also function as an adverb or conjunction, *this* does not.)

I'm not familiar with Portuguese but it sounds like you can't translate those terms using *this* and *that*.